# CDF of Joint Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability

For X, Y two independent Random Variables with identical distribution
$$X,Y ~f(t)  = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}, \text{ for } t\in (0,+\infty)$$
I want to find the cdf of $$Z = \vert X-Y\vert$$
I use $$F_Z(t) = P(-t<X-Y<t) = \int^{+\infty}_{x=-\infty}\int^{x+t}_{x-t} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dydx$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}(e^{\lambda t}-e^{-\lambda t})$$
which should be clearly wrong as it is a monotonically increasing function.
Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Look at the support for the density function.  $t\in(0;\infty)$.  Now look at the boundaries for your integral.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that the lower bound of the first integral must be $0$, but I think you had interpreted it as zero since otherwise the integral would diverge. The second thing is that the lower bound of the second integral is also incorrect, since the density of $Y$ is zero if $y$ is negative. The last thing is that a CDF can be increasing so that is certainly not a problem. The problem you should worry about is that the function you got goes to infinity if $t\to\infty$.

Okay, you do it correctly like this 
\begin{align} 
F_Z(t) =P(-t<Y-X<t) =\int^\infty_0 \int^{x+t}_{\max\{x -t, 0\}} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy\, dx 
\end{align} 
Since the density of $Y$ is zero if $y$ is negative. The  calculations is left for you.

Answer (score 0):

$X,Y$ are only supported over positive real values.   Integration boundaries must include this restriction.

$$\begin{split}F_Z(t) &= \mathsf P(0<X<t, 0<Y<X+t)+\mathsf P(t\leqslant X, X-t\leqslant Y<X+t)\\[2ex] &= \left(\int_0^t\int_0^{x+t} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda(x+y)}~\mathsf d y~\mathsf dx+\int_t^\infty\int_{x-t}^{x+t} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda(x+y)}~\mathsf d y~\mathsf dx\right)\mathbf 1_{t\in(0;\infty)}\\[2ex]&~~\vdots\end{split}$$

Comment: I was thinking the only problem should be the term x-t as well, but I don't know how to make it positive, thank you!